# Partial results are valid but processing is incomplete: mod_fcgid: can't get data from http client

Tags: php, upload, mod-fcgid

I would like to upload large files up to 50GB.

I edited my php.ini

```
max_execution_time = 18000
max_input_time = 18000
post_max_size = 50G
upload_max_filesize = 50G
```

I increased mod_fcgid values in my vhost

```
IdleTimeout 18000
ProcessLifeTime 18000
FcgidMaxRequestLen 64424509440
FcgidIOTimeout 18000
```

I can upload files around 2-3GB maximum, but for more there are two cases:

- No error in apache logs for files around 10GB
- An error for files around 5GB : (70008)Partial results are valid but processing is incomplete: mod_fcgid: can't get data from http client

The site (if it can help you) : http://filetransfer.fr

Thank you in advance to any one who will help me !

*Debian 7, apache 2.2.22, PHP 5.4.45*

Comment: Have you tried setting SSLRenegBufferSize to 1073741824 for instance?

Comment: Do you have 32 or 64 bit system? How much free space you have? PHP transfers the whole uploaded file into local filesystem before your code can run at all and that will obviously fail if the file is too big.

Comment: Have you solved this issue? If so please answer it yourself.

Comment: First, thank you for your answers and sorry for delay !
- fritzmg : Yes i tried but it changed nothing :/
- MikkoRantalainen : Debian 64 and i have 1,7 TB Free in /home.
@Ahti : I haven't managed to solve this problem but some students said me that it's impossible to upload files > 5 GB by using $_POST, i have to use FTP protocol... I don't know if it's true but that would be too many changes to do in my code...

Answer (score -2):

We got that only with Internet Explorer / Edge.
As long we use something different everything's OK.

It seems compressed content in IE / Edge is somehow buggy.
You may try to disable compression and check if that goes away.